# Amazon S3 option missing in Deja Dup?

Tags: 11.10, deja-dup

I wanted to restore my backup (created with Deja Dup on Fedora 15) from Amazon S3, but the option to set up Amazon as storage location in Ubuntu's Deja Dup seems to be missing. 
I only have Ubuntu One, SSH, FTP, WebDAV, Win Share, local folder and custom location.

Am I missing some package(s), is it some bug, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong?
Uncle Google refuses to help... :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install the [python-boto[image: Install python-boto]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-boto)
 package.

Comment: And if you want to backup to Rackspace Cloud Files, install python-cloudfiles

Comment: How utterly unintuitive.