# How can I use an existing S3 bucket in Backup?

Tags: deja-dup, aws

I have an existing Amazon S3 bucket in the Oregon region. How can I use it as the backup location in Backup?

### Details

- I've [enabled the Amazon S3 backup location](https://askubuntu.com/q/67095/1859), but I don't see a way to specify which bucket to use. When I start backups for the first time, it automatically creates a new bucket with a name I don't want in a region I don't want to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it's a bit hidden.  You can do it on the console:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.DejaDup.S3 bucket 'MYBUCKETNAME'`

Or you can do it graphically:

- Install the package 'dconf-tools'
- Run dconf-editor
- Browse to /org/gnome/deja-dup/s3
- Edit the bucket key