# Upgrade to 15.04 breaks deja dup backups to Amazon S3?

Tags: backup, 15.04, deja-dup

I had configured deja dup to backup to an Amazon S3 bucket as described in this question: [How can I use an existing S3 bucket in Backup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217230/how-can-i-use-an-existing-s3-bucket-in-backup) and in more detail in this [post](http://blog.domenech.org/2013/01/backing-up-ubuntu-using-deja-dup-backup-and-aws-s3.html), which worked smoothly.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 however, the backup fails with an `unknown error` and this cryptic traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1500, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1327, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1047, in ProcessCommandLine
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 221, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 207, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_single.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.resetConnection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_single.py", line 183, in resetConnection
    self.conn = get_connection(self.scheme, self.parsed_url, self.storage_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_single.py", line 97, in get_connection
    assert scheme == 's3'
AssertionError
```

Any suggestions on how to address or debug this?

Comment: Is `python-boto` installed? Can you backup using other backends?

Comment: @Jan Yes, `python-boto` is installed; and yes, other backup methods work fine.

Comment: Note that this same error also occurs when using duplicity directly with Amazon S3.  Also note that installing the latest `boto` using `pip install` instead of `apt-get` still does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have any experience with Python?  If so, then you may want to look into manually editing that file to see what's going on (e.g., that's not a data error, that's a failed assertion; you might want to try printing the value of "scheme" to a file or something; also, this is usually a bad idea, but (1) there is a very low probability that anything you do here could actually mess your backup scheme up and (2) you might be able to fix a bug in Deja-Dup itself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem impacts the underlying backend software, `duplicity` as well as deja dup.  I filed a bug report for duplicity, which has now both confirmed the bug and issued a patch, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1453232 This bug affects duplicity version 0.7.01 and is fixed in 0.7.02.